# How to do C language calculation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I want to do some simulation of C language calculation in Python.
For example, unsigned short, single precision float ...

```
ushort(0xffff) + 1 -> 0
0.1f * 0.1f -> ...
```

Are there some library to do this in Python?

I can use ctypes to create unsigned short, single float, but they
cann't do math operation:

```
a = c_uint16(0xffff)
b = c_uint16(0x01)
a+b -> TypeError
```

Or, I can use numpy:

```
>>> np.uint16(0xffff) + np.uint16(0x01)
Warning: overflow encountered in ushort_scalars
0
```

but it's very slow comparing to Python's normal calculation:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("a+b", "import numpy as np;a=np.uint16(0xfffe);b=np.uint16(0x01)")
0.35577465681618037
>>> timeit.timeit("0xfffe+0x01")
0.022638104432360251
>>> timeit.timeit("np.uint16(0xfffe) + np.uint16(0x01)", "import numpy as np")
5.904765399236851
```

Edit:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("a+b", "a=0xfffe;b=0x01")
0.040062221014295574
```

Comment: how about: `def add(a,b): return (a+b) % 65536` ?

Answer (score 6):

When compiling `0xfffe+0x01`, this will be folded into the constant `65535`.  You aren't timing how long the addition takes -- you are just measuring the time of loading the constant:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("0xfffe+0x01", "", "eval"))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (65535)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

The addition of NumPy scalars is slower than adding built-in integers nevertheless, but it won't get better than that in pure Python.  Consider using [Cython](http://cython.org/) -- it will allow you to declare types and execute the computations in C speed.  Alternatively, try to vectorise your code in NumPy (that is, if speed really matters).

Comment: yes, the gerund vs. infinitive thing doesn't make a lot of sense does it? I was thinking about it after I saw this. For example "try to use cython" and "try using cython" are both idiomatic English, but they mean subtly different things; the former means something like "as a rule, use cython if you can," while the latter is closer to "consider using cython." (And for what it's worth, it should probably be "to learn better English.") All that said, I did mean it, about your posts being spotless, generally. Now that I know you don't mind a direct edit, perhaps I'll do that next time.

Comment: @senderle: Thanks again -- I'll clarify the message in my profile!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function for each operation using modulo `%` with `2**sizeof` (in your case, 2**16 or 65536)

```
def add(a, b, mod=2**16):
    return (a+b) % mod

def sub(a, b, mod=2**16):
    return (a-b) % mod
```

and any other function you need.

```
>>> add(0xffff, 1)
0
>>> sub(10, 20)
65526
```

Note this will work only for unsigned types. For signed ones, you can use half the value used to mod (i.e. 2**15) and will have to validate the result before applying modulo

Comment: Thanks, your method is useful for integers. For single floats, I am considering using ctypes call some DLL.